# Write file in Azure DataLake in AzureML

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using "data assets" to read data from azure datalake into azureML workspace.

But I would like to know how do I write data in azure datalake. I have a pandas dataframe and would like to save it as csv/parquet in datalake.

Code:

```
import mltable
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

mlClient = MLClient.from_config(credential=DefaultAzureCredential())
dataAsset = mlClient.data.get(name="MyDataAsset", version="1")

pathTest = {
    'folder': dataAsset.path
}

tblTest = mltable.from_parquet_files(paths=[pathTest])
dfBaseTest = tblTest.to_pandas_dataframe()  # ok, here is my pandas dataframe

##############
ML operations.....result: dfResult

How to save dfResult in my dataLake. Is it possible to use the data asset: "MyDataAsset"? Or data asset is only read?
##############
```

Thanks, RishabhM. Works.

As I already have the folders created in datalake, I did it like this:

```
import os
from azure.storage.filedatalake import (
    DataLakeServiceClient,
    DataLakeDirectoryClient,
    FileSystemClient
)
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
account_url = f"https://<Account-Name>.dfs.core.windows.net"
token_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url, credential=token_credential)

file_system_client = service_client.get_file_system_client(file_system="myFileSystem")
directory_client = file_system_client.get_directory_client("Folder1/Folder2")

dfPandas.to_csv("./data.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8', sep=';')

file_client = directory_client.get_file_client("data.csv")

with open(file=os.path.join("", "data.csv"), mode="rb") as data:
    file_client.upload_data(data, overwrite=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to upload data is by using `Azure Data Lake Storage client library for Python`.

```py
import os
from azure.storage.filedatalake import (
    DataLakeServiceClient,
    DataLakeDirectoryClient,
    FileSystemClient
)
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
account_url = f"https://<Account-Name>.dfs.core.windows.net"
token_credential = DefaultAzureCredential()

service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url, credential=token_credential)
file_system_client = service_client.create_file_system(file_system="dataasset2")
directory_client = file_system_client.create_directory("test")
file_client = directory_client.get_file_client("data.csv")

with open(file=os.path.join("", "data.csv"), mode="rb") as data:
    file_client.upload_data(data, overwrite=True)
```

[image]